# React component to output database info

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, create-react-app

I've making a recipe website and having trouble putting to words what I'm trying to do.

I have a component (home.js) which I'm trying to display different recipe posts on.

My thought was that I could make a component called recipe.js that would just have the structure of how a recipe post would be laid out. Then, all the recipe information would be displayed in that structure as it pulls all the recipe info from my database. This way I wouldn't have to have an individual component for each recipe.

Am I right in going about this? I'm a bit lost as to how I'm meant to do this or even what I would google to help accomplish this.

I'd be grateful for a push in the right direction.

Comment: Use a map approach to display an array of items with the same component. I'll advice you check these doc - https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#basic-list-component and https://scrimba.com/learn/frontend/mapping-components-in-react-cDZbahv

Comment: @kimobrian254 thank you, I'll check these out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a total React pro but I think a useFetch would work: it would pull info from the database using the props passed in.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFetch } from 'react-async';

export const Recipe = (props) => {
  const { data, error } = useFetch(`https://swapi.co/api/people/${id}/`, {
    headers: { accept: "application/json" },
  })
  if (error) return error.message
  if (data) return (<div className="recipe"></div>)
  return null;
}
```